# jquery select table columns

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am working on selecting a specific table's cells.

Some cells have a class of "testOff", and I'm attempting to change the table row to a different color, if the class exists.

here's what I have so far:

```
$("table#customersTable td.testOff").each(function(){

    $(this).closest("tr").css("background-color","#F6CCDA");

});
```

I must be missing something, since it's not showing the background color for any of the cells.
Does anyone see an error with how I'm selecting?

Comment: This should work, could we see the HTML?  And you don't need `.each()`, you can just `$("table#customersTable td.testOff").closest("tr").css("background-color","#F6CCDA");`

Comment: do the `td`'s themselves have a background color? it will override the `tr` if so.. you may need to select the closest `tr` 's children `td`s or `td.testoff` and it's siblings, to show the colour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
$('td.testOff').closest('tr').addClass('highlightColour');
```

CSS:

```
.highlight,
.highlight td /* this part's important, and ensures that the 'highlight' colour is seen in the td elements */
{ 
    background-color: #ffa;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6V7vf/).

Incidentally: you don't need the `each()`, as the selector will return, and work with, an array of elements already.

References:

- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [:has](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector:

```
$('#customersTable tr:has(td.testOff)').css('background-color', '#f6ccda');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#customersTable td.testOff').closest('tr').addClass('highlightColour').css("background-color","#F6CCDA");
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/uXFsa/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("td.testOff").parent().children().css("background-color","#F6CCDA");
```

as per my earlier question, just in case it's the `td` cells themselves you need to target to override a previous setting

[`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) as I also mentioned in my comments, would only select the cells on either side of the `.testOff` - this finds all the children of it's parent `tr`